# The Fate of the Gobi

Tags: climate, geography, geology

The Gobi Desert is what ecologists call an "interior desert" because it's too far away for water to reach.

Now imagine that the Caspian Drainage Basin to the west has experienced a 75-meter rise in sea levels.  Then imagine Asia's east coast to the east experiencing the same thing.

Would the Gobi Desert still exist with these changes?  If so, will it be the same Gobi we know?

Comment: To be honest, I'm more concerned about what happened to the rest of the world with this drastic a rise in sea level.

Comment: @Frostfyre I will be really concerned when the OP begins buying terrains in the Gobi...

Comment: @SJuan76 Now I'm looking for signs saying "Beachfront property coming soon!"

Comment: @Frostfyre  Focus on the scenario at hand.

Comment: @Frostfyre: But the Caspian Sea is not connected (except, I think, by a canal) to the rest of the world ocean.  In fact, it isn't strictly speaking a sea at all, but a very large salt lake, akin to North America's Great Salt Lake, Pyramid Lake, &c.  So an increase in rainfall or inflow could raise the level substantially before it overflowed into the Black Sea. Its surface is currently ~30m below sea level.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspian_Sea

Comment: @jamesqf  Go to the floodmaps website, and you can see how rising sea levels affect the Caspian.

Comment: @JohnWDailey:  Did you mean this one: http://flood.firetree.net/  Doesn't work - all I see is a blank page with a few bits of text around it.  In any case, rising sea levels wouldn't affect the Caspian directly (or Death Valley, the Dead Sea, &c) unless the rise is enough to surmount the land barrier separating it from the ocean.  I don't know where to find a topo map that shows how high the land is between the Caspian & Black Seas...

Comment: If you look at western sahara, having a salty body of water close-by can be completely useless in fixing a desert. 
The climate is influenced by many things.

Comment: @jamesqf  No, here:  http://www.floodmap.net/

Comment: @JohnWDailey: Sorry, but that one doesn't work either, just black.  Probably based off the recent update to Google Maps or similar - something done by idiot programmers who assume everyone's going to use their choice of colors &c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gobi Desert is over 1000 meters above sea level, so a 75 meter rise would not directly affect it.

The rise would affect the Caspian sea and the area around it but that is a huge distance away. To the east even a 75 meter rise does not have a huge effect, Beijing is now by the sea and big chunks of China are flooded but they are also still a long way away.

So the likely answer is that it may get a little wetter or a little smaller or both - but there are unlikely to be huge changes. These things are always unpredictable though as the increased water areas may then lead to changes in the weather patterns in the area which may then go on to itself have huge and unexpected consequences.